# HttpURLConnection - uknown format (magic number 376)

Tags: java, android, http, gzip, httpurlconnection

I call a HTTP GET request from my Android app:

```
String urlString = "http://my.service.com/foo";
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("X-MY-HEADER", "1");
conn.setDoOutput(false);

int code = conn.getResponseCode();
```

The last line throws an exception:

```
java.io.IOException: unknown format (magic number 376)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:101)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:468)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:666)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
```

HTTP engine seems to use gzip internally, which causes the exception. I didn't ask for any compression though. Why is this exception thrown? Can I turn it off somehow? What does this magic number 376 mean?

Comment: Are you missing the conn.connect(); from example https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download

Comment: I suggest that you use [HttpClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

Comment: @LanceJava I used to use it and I was happy, but they say it is deprecated for Android 6.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! According to developer.android.com:

> By default, this implementation of **HttpURLConnection** requests that
>   servers use gzip compression and it automatically decompresses the
>   data for callers of getInputStream(). The Content-Encoding and
>   Content-Length response headers are cleared in this case. Gzip
>   compression can be disabled by setting the acceptable encodings in the
>   request header:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

Comment: Thanks, bro! You made my day. I couldn't get content-length, the server uses gzip.